# Is it possible to run multiple update queries in one using Joomla? 

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to run many SQL update queries at one time using JOOMLA 2.5. Below my code:

```
require_once '../includes/framework.php';  
$query = "UPDATE #__mytable SET myfield='value' where id=1; UPDATE #__mytable SET  
myfield='value' where id=2; UPDATE #__mytable SET myfield='value' where id=3;";  
$db = JFactory::getDbo();  
$db->setQuery($query);  
$db->query();
```

But it shows me a syntax error. I tried to test directly in MYSQL and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP does not allow multiple queries by default. You can force it to do so by adding a parameter to mysql_connect, but I wouldn't recommend it (it opens huge security holes for SQL injections).

I don't know how JFactory handles this, but I would be surprised if it were different.

More infos about it: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#91669

Comment: Ok, so I think it will be better to use a loop. I also try to mesure the time that will take (**0.095135 second**) and it seems ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you set the same value to every entry you can do it in a single query: `UPDATE #__mytable SET myfield='value' where id IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the same values.

Comment: what about using mysqli? it suports multiple query and joomla supports mysqli

Comment: Given that all updates are related to a single table, also the `CASE` costruct may be a viable solution.

Comment: While this still is true, the [newer answer by Demis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43990040/212107) is much more helpful. Please upvote it, it should be the accepted answer by now.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `JDatabaseDriver::splitSql()` to
split a string of multiple queries into an array of individual queries, and run them once at a time.

This is how the internal extensions installer works.

Don't worry about comments, they will be stripped off.

```
$sql = "UPDATE #__mytable SET myfield='value' where id=1; UPDATE #__mytable SET myfield='value' where id=2; UPDATE #__mytable SET myfield='value' where id=3;";

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$queries = JDatabaseDriver::splitSql($sql);
foreach ($queries as $query)
{
    try
    {
        $db->setQuery($query)->execute();
    }
    catch (JDatabaseExceptionExecuting $e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```